# Spring Cloud Data Flow Server for Kubernetes installation

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

The installation steps for SCDF for Kubernetes requires choosing a messaging solution apart from a datastore. Our use case for using SCDF revolves around using only Tasks which will be Spring Boot apps with Spring batch support. So is it mandatory to still install Kafka or RabitMQ or can those be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats on the 1st StackOverflow post!

If you're interested only in Task/Batch-only features in SCDF, you could cleanly disable the streaming and the analytics features from SCDF.

Please have a look at the [feature-toggles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#enable-disable-specific-features) listed in the reference guide.

In your case, you can disable streams and analytics through `SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_STREAMS_ENABLED` and `SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_ANALYTICS_ENABLED` properties set to `false` respectively.

Specifically, you'd have to add/update these 2 key-value properties in [server-deployment.yaml](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/blob/master/src/kubernetes/server/server-deployment.yaml). Once when you do that, you can skip Message Broker and Redis from the deployment list.

Comment: I could deploy the SCDF server by switching off those feature toggles. Also, I did not apply the Kubernetes configMaps for Kafka or RabbitMQ since analytics and streaming are switched off. Instead I just applied a different configMap which defines the database to be MS SQL server and related configurations related to it. Thereafter I tried running the Spring provided Timestamp task which I loaded from tasks from [link](bit.ly/Clark-GA-task-applications-docker). The timestamp task failed to launch. I did not see any pods getting launched either.

Comment: Am I missing something ?  I will post a separate question about this with details about my SCDF server installation and the error seen in the SCDF server pod.